# How to add error validation to method inside a service in Ionic app?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to add some error handling to the below function in my Ionic / Angular app:

Conversation-Detail Component:

```
this.conversationsSub = this.conversationsService
    .getConversation(this.conversationId)
        .subscribe(
            conversation => {
            this.usersSub = this.usersService.getUserByUserId(this.conversation.mechanicId).subscribe(
                user => {
                    loadingEl.dismiss();
                });
            }, 
            error => {
            loadingEl.dismiss();
            this.alertCtrl.create({
              header: 'An Error Occurred',
              message: 'Conversation not found. Please try again later.',
              buttons: [
                {
                  text: 'Okay',
                  handler: () => {
                    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
                  }
                }
              ]
            }).then(alertEl => {
              alertEl.present();
            })
          });
```

So when I pass in an invalid value to `this.conversationId`, the `alertController` above displays the expected error message.

However, I still get this error message in the console in relation to `this.conversationsService.getConversation()`:

> Cannot read property 'userId' of null

Here is the method in Conversation Service:

```
 getConversation(id: String) {
    return this.http
      .get<ConversationData>(
        `https://mychanic-60927.firebaseio.com/conversations/${id}.json`
      )
      .pipe(
        map(convoData => {
          return new Conversation(
            id,
            convoData.userId,
            convoData.mechanicId,
            convoData.messages
          );
        })
      )
  }
```

Can someone please tell me how I can handle this error if `this.conversationId` is invalid?

I tried to add `convoData?.userId`, but that didn't work.

Comment: can you include what is inside of `Conversation` class

Comment: Hi John, do you mean the Conversation component or the Conversation service?

Comment: I mean this one `return new Conversation` and also what is the value of `convoData`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like?

```
getConversation(id: String) {
    return this.http
    .get<ConversationData>(
        `https://mychanic-60927.firebaseio.com/conversations/${id}.json`
    )
    .pipe(
        map(convoData => {
            convoData !== null 
                ? return new Conversation(
                    id,
                    convoData.userId,
                    convoData.mechanicId,
                    convoData.messages
                )
                : throw {'msg' : 'Invalid Id'};
         })
    )
}
```

or if the desired outcome is not an error then you could simply replace the throw line with of() and return an empty observable by moving return to before the null check.